# Issues creating ARM template: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager

Good morning, I am trying to follow tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/create-azure-resource-manager-template-vs-code/3-exercise-create-and-deploy-template?pivots=powershell&source=learn) to create an ARM template. I followed the steps and when I try to deploy I get the following error:

ERROR:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
At line:4 char:1
+ New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], JsonReaderException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

When I run:

```
$templateFile="azuredeploy.json"
$today=Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy"
$deploymentName="blanktemplate-"+"$today"
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
  -Name $deploymentName `
  -TemplateFile $templateFile
```

the azuredeploy.json file is located in my C drive.

My powershell AZ version

```
Get-InstalledModule -Name Az

Version    Name                                Repository           Description
-------    ----                                ----------           -----------
8.1.0      Az                                  PSGallery            Microsoft Azure PowerShell - Cmdlets to manage resources in Azure. This module is compatible with Powe...
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the template you are trying to deploy.

Comment: Have you modified the template? If you are just using the template as-is from the referenced URL, does it work?

Comment: I have not modified the template, this is what it looks like: {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {}
}

Answer (score 0):

We have also tried with the [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENT***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/create-azure-resource-manager-template-vs-code/3-exercise-create-and-deploy-template?pivots=powershell&source=learn) which you are following,

***And after  looking into your error and PowerShell script for deployment  is seems you haven't provided the `PATH` correctly*** .

Steps for deployment to your resource group is ;

*After build the infra you need to save it ,for example we have created one blank resource as shown in the document and saved in file called* `stack_armdeploytest.json` .

[image]

***Then run the below command to connect to your azure account and subscription*** .

```
connect-AzAccount
Select-AzSubscription -Subscription ***ID***
```

[image]

***For deployment using*** [**`New-AzResourceGroupDeployment`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroupdeployment?view=azps-8.3.0#examples) , *we need to provide the correct & complete* **`path of the template file location`** *where it is located and then we can deploy the blank resource or any resource to our Environment*.

***For example:-***

```
$templateFile="C:\Users\devicename\source\repos\stack_armdeploytest.json"
$today=Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy"
$deploymentName="blanktemplate-"+"$today"
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
  -Name $deploymentName `
  -TemplateFile $templateFile
```

***Successfully deployed:-***
[image]
[image]